# How to know which coroutines were done with asyncio.wait()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have two `StreamReader` objects and want to read from them in a loop. I'm using `asyncio.wait` like this:

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    [reader.read(1000), freader.read(1000)],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Now `done.pop()` gives me the future that finished first. The problem is I don't know how to find which `read()` operation completed. I tried putting `[reader.read(1000), freader.read(1000)]` in a `tasks` variable and comparing the done future with those. But this seems to be incorrect since the done future is equal to none of the original tasks. So how am I supposed to find which coroutine was finished?

Comment: You need to create tasks from your calls and pass *those* to `wait` - see e.g. [this example](https://websockets.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro.html#both).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep. That does it. Thanks. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Jolly good, will do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a separate task for each `.read` call, and pass those tasks to `.wait`. You can then check where the *tasks* are in the results.

```
reader_task = asyncio.ensure_future(reader.read(1000))
...

done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    [reader_task, ...],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
)

if reader_task in done:
   ...

...
```

See e.g. [this example](https://websockets.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro.html#both) from the `websockets` documentation.

Comment: Also please note that one common mistake is to ignore that `asyncio.wait` can be cancelled (usually when the containing coroutine is cancelled) but that the tasks it creates (or the ones you create and pass) **aren't**. I usually end-up wrapping my `asyncio.wait` calls with a `try`/`finally` that explicitly cancels the tasks. Annoying and poorly documented at the moment.